# "#+BIBLIOGRAPHY" tag not working

Tags: org-mode, org-export, reftex-mode

I have a simple file looking like this,

```
#+TITLE: Title Here
#+AUTHOR: Author Name


Citation here [[cite:key_name]]

#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: refs plain
```

In the same directory I have `refs.bib`,

```
@MISC {key_name,
    TITLE = {Informal derivation (and interpretation) of Substitution Rule from Chain Rule?},
    AUTHOR = {user1180576 (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/629687/user1180576)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354744 (version: 2019-09-13)},
    EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354744},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3354744}
}
```

Now when I run `org-latex-export-to-pdf`, I don't get the references and looking at the Tex file produced,

```latex
% Created 2020-06-23 Tue 02:55
% Intended LaTeX compiler: xelatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
[snip]
\begin{document}

\maketitle
Citation here \cite{key_name}
\end{document}
```

The `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and `\bibliography{refs}` are missing. What am I doing wrong?

If I put `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and `\bibliography{refs}` in my org file than everything works fine.

**Edit:**
Following are my `org-ref` configurations,

```lisp
;; org-ref
(use-package org-ref
  :ensure t
  :custom
  (org-ref-completion-library 'org-ref-ivy-cite))
```

And my `org-latex-pdf-process` is indeed set to `(list "latexmk -xelatex -shell-escape -bibtex -f -pdf %f")`.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are using [John Kitchin's org-ref package](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref), correct? And two comments: 1) I'm not sure that underscores can be used in keys and 2) you need to modify your `org-latex-pdf-process` to invoke `bibtex`. See the link for more details

Comment: If you are not using `org-ref`, you probably need to `(require 'ox-bibtex)`.

Comment: I am using `org-ref`. Though, I thought it's invocation was optional (when the bibliography style and file links are defined). I did not install `ox-bibtex`, does it not come by default like `ox-latex/html`? I will edit my question with my `org-ref` configs.

Comment: I may be completely wrong (I know next to nothing about org-ref), but I don't think `org-ref` uses `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: ` at all. It's only `ox-bibtex` that uses it I think. See [org Emacs Lisp Package Archive](https://orgmode.org/elpa.html) for the `org-plus-contrib` package or get `ox-bibtex.el` from the [Org mode git repo](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/raw/master/contrib/lisp/ox-bibtex.el).

Comment: Yeah my issue actually was not having the `org-plus-contrib`. I was assuming that `ox-bibtex.el` comes with the default emacs' org.